# How to POST ManyToMany Data with Json?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

How to POST ManyToMany Data with Json? I have a data like this:

[image]

#### model.py

```
from django.db import models


class Diet(models.Model):
    date = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    building = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    restaurants = models.ManyToManyField('Restaurant')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.building


class Restaurant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    menus = models.ManyToManyField('DietMenu')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class DietMenu(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

#### api.py

```
from .models import Diet
from .models import Restaurant
from .models import DietMenu
from rest_framework import serializers, viewsets


class DietMenuSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DietMenu
        fields = ('name', 'price')


class DietMenuViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = DietMenu.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DietMenuSerializer


class RestaurantSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    menus = DietMenuSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Restaurant
        fields = ('name', 'menus')


class RestaurantViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Restaurant.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RestaurantSerializer


class DietSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    restaurants = RestaurantSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Diet
        fields = ('date', 'building', 'location', 'restaurants')


class DietViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Diet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DietSerializer
```

And I get a json of the data like this.
[image]

```
import requests


class DjangoJson(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.url = "url"

    def set_diet_date(self):
        self.url = "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/diet/?format=json"

    def get(self):
        self.set_diet_date()
        request = requests.get(self.url)
        document = request.json()
        return document

    def post(self, param):
        requests.post(self.url, json=param)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    json = DjangoJson()
    doc = json.get()[0]
    json.post(doc)
```

Then I POST this json by using the requests library.  But the restaurant field is empty.
[image]

Is there any way to POST ManyToMany data with Json?
Thanks.

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations

Comment: Sorry for late. It helps me. read_only is problem. Thanks.